# algorithm to expand points radially from center of 5x5 grid

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to create an algorithm that takes a 5x5 grid and expands it outwards each iteration. it takes only one parameter which is the amount of iterations. the grid will always be 5x5 and start with a single unit in the center

```
expandOutwards(int n) //n is iterations,
```

```
before iteration the grid looks like this:
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . x . .
. . . . .
. . . . .

Iteration 1:

. . . . .
. . x . .
. x x x .
. . x . .
. . . . .

iteration 2

. . x . .
. x x x .
x x x x x
. x x x .
. . x . .

iteration 3:
. x x x .
x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
. x x x .

and finally iteration 4:

x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
```

Thank you

Comment: Please share your **attempt** and specify what are the problems you've encountered? Use *edit* button to update the question, or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73920021/edit). Also, get familiar with the guide-lines on how to ask questions [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If your grid is always 5x5 you can of course just hard-code the output for each `n`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a computational solution, assuming zero-based indexes, you can use the condition

```
|x-2| + |y-2| ≤ i
```

to assign the symbols and fill the whole matrix. (This is the so-called L1 norm.)

---

You can also work incrementally by setting to `x` all points such that

```
|x-2| + |y-2| = i
```

but the loops are a little complicated.